# Use variable with preamble

Tags: beamer, titles

In my research, I need to write posters occasionally (with beamer).
Can I define something like this in a different file (as preamble.tex,
with other things)

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
  \begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
    \Title{
      \begin{center}
        Variable_Title of the poster
      \end{center}
    }
    \Huge{
      \begin{center}
        Variable_Author of the poster
      \end{center}
    }
    \LARGE{
      \begin{center}
        Variable_Affiliation
      \end{center}
    }
  \end{minipage}
```

And then in main tex,

```
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}
value of title; value of author, value of affiliation etc?
\end{document}
```

Any idea?

I am bit sceptic, as many things are going even before \begin{documents} and not sure, if we can add such "variables".

Looking for ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a macro in your preamble that takes the values of title, author and affliation as parameters e.g.:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\displayheader}[3]{% <-- [3] tells the macro to expect three parameters
\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}%
\Title{%
  \begin{center}%
    #1%  <--- First Argument, title
  \end{center}%
}%
\Huge{%
  \begin{center}%
    #2% <--- Second Argument, author
  \end{center}%
}%
\LARGE{%
  \begin{center}%
    #3% <--- Third Argument, affliation
  \end{center}%
}%
\end{minipage}%
}%
```

Then you can use it as follows in your main tex.

```
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}
\displayheader{title}{author}{affliation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are interested in a title page for your presentation. `beamer` offers a lot of facilities to do this.

You can setup the following information in your header:

- `\title[short form]{long form}`
- `\subtitle[short form]{long form}`
- `\author[short form]{long form}`
- `\date[short form]{long form}`
- `\institue[short form]{long form}`
- `\titlegraphic{text}`
- `\subject{text}`
- `\keywords{text}`

To print out the title page you can simple say `\maketitle` which is equal to `\frame{\titlepage}`

So related to your question you can do the following:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{preamble.tex}
\documentclass{beamer}
%some other settings
\end{filecontents}
\input{preamble}

\author{Rudra}
\title{my title}
\institute{Some institute}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]